# Network Interfaces Plugging skip eth0, skip wlan0 ...done. (wlan0 unreachable)

Tags: networking, wireless, wifi, ethernet

I have set up static Ethernet and WiFi but after rpi-update wlan no longer works. The rpi-update could just be a coincidence though.
What happens is that the static IP shows up when scanned with Advanced IP scanner but connections to it timeout and that includes ping command. Network interfaces does not throw an error during boot. There is however this line that might be related but I could not find any info on it:

```
Network Interfaces Plugging skip eth0, skip wlan0 ... done.
```

What does this mean and should it "skip" anything. If not what setting affects this.

If I plug in Ethernet it works as expected and if I unplug it after boot, WiFi starts to work in a little while.

Here's my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.14
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet static
address 192.168.0.14
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to allocate the same static address to 2 interfaces `eth0` and `wlan0`

Assign different addresses to each.

Comment: I thought of that but then that's really stupid implementation. The whole point of static ip is so that you would always know it, now it will change based on network device... really silly unfortunately...

Comment: You may not like it, but that is the way IP works. An address would be allocated to `eth0`, regardless of whether anything is connected - that is the point of `static`. When the wireless eventually wakes there will be a conflict. Behaviour in this case is undefined.

Comment: It's not just that I don't like it, having multiple static IP addresses per device does not make sense. Why does the wifi start working after Ethernet is disconnected after boot but not when only wifi is present at boot? Seems like it should not work either way.

Comment: Also, I changed ip of the wifi and while it shows up I still cannot connect to it.

Comment: @DominicM - does the Pi have a decent power supply? Mine can sometimes struggle with a 1 amp power supply plus Ethernet and WiFi, but works OK with a 2 amp one.

Comment: I would be amazed if it was a power issue. Voltage at test points is around 4.96V so I don't think that's an issue.

Comment: What's odd is if I boot with wifi only then connect Ethernet which works and then remove Ethernet cable wifi starts to work on the defined ip (either different or same as ethernet ip).

Comment: What you want is not normal IP operation. If you want to assign the same address to 2 physically separate interfaces you will need to deactivate the other. The `ifconfig eth0 down` should let you do this. See `man ifconfig`

Comment: @Milliways well, wifi doesn't even work with different ip when booted with wifi only. Also doesn't pi bring down the other interface automatically? You can't use both at the same time so if it doesn't bring it down what does it do?

Comment: @DominicM You can certainly use multiple interfaces simultaneously. You have made problems for yourself by trying non standard settings. I would suggest you try using WiFi with standard (`DHCP`) settings and no ethernet. If it won't work try asking a new question, but the issue with the hundreds of others who have WiFi problems is power supply - you need a powered hub.

Comment: Like I said the wifi works just not when ethernet is removed so there's no point in you repeating the same thing, if it was power related it wouldn't work at all let alone for hours with no issue. It also worked with DHCP before and I don't see how static ip is non-standard.